MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size'
I am developing an e-commerce website using ASP.NET 6 MVC and MySQL is my database.
This is my sp to get the data of all the products
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `product_list`()
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        p.p_code AS ProductCode, 
        p.p_name AS ProductName, 
        p.category AS Category, 
        SUM(pv.stock) AS TotalStock, 
        i.i_name AS ImageName
    FROM 
        tbl_products p 
    JOIN 
        tbl_productvariants pv ON p.p_Id = pv.product_id
    JOIN 
        (
            SELECT product_id, i_name 
            FROM tbl_images 
            WHERE (product_id, i_id) IN (
                SELECT product_id, MIN(i_id) 
                FROM tbl_images 
                GROUP BY product_id
            )
        ) i ON p.p_Id = i.product_id 
    GROUP BY 
        p.p_Id, p.p_code, p.p_name, p.category, i.i_name
    ORDER BY 
        p.p_Id;
END

when I am calling this sp from ASP.NET, it is showing out of sort memory error
I have tried to make changes in my.cnf file
[mysqld]
sort_buffer_size = 2M

This is basically a bug/regression in MySQL 8.0.23. You could increase the buffer even more, but in some cases even that doesn't help.
Improving your query would be the first thing to try, to get rid of the sorting altogether.
The nested subquery on tbl_images can be improved by using window functions. And instead of one giant outer GROUP BY, you could move the stock calculation into a subquery.
SELECT 
    p.p_code AS ProductCode, 
    p.p_name AS ProductName, 
    p.category AS Category, 
    pv.TotalStock, 
    i.i_name AS ImageName
FROM 
    tbl_products p 
JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            pv.product_id,
            SUM(pv.stock) AS TotalStock
        FROM tbl_productvariants pv
    ) pv ON p.p_Id = pv.product_id
JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            i.product_id,
            i.i_name,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.product_id ORDER BY i.i_id) AS rn
        FROM tbl_images i 
    ) i ON p.p_Id = i.product_id AND i.rn = 1
ORDER BY 
    p.p_Id;

Finally, you can check the query plan and ensure that all tables have proper indexing. I would expect the following indexes
tbl_products (p_ID)     -- primary key
tbl_productvariants (product_id, variant_id, stock)
tbl_images (product_id, i_id, i_name)

